# unknown error upon rebuilding WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I rebuilt a project file by creating a project with the same name in a new solution, copying that project file over the corrupt project file, and re-including the project files within the solution.

I am now getting the error Error

> 6 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'UserConsole.MainWindowView.InitializeComponent()' and
>   'UserConsole.MainWindowView.InitializeComponent()'    C:\Code\PollPublicDataStock\PollPublicDataStock\UserConsole\MainWindowView.xaml.cs  29  13

Uh, those are the same methods... where is the ambiguity?

Comment: do you have two `MainWindowView.xaml.cs` ?

Comment: actually along the lines of what @Bolu said, you're likely to have two `MainWindowView.xaml` codebehinds (VS does that sometimes). Expand the xaml to see if it shows you two files. if it does, delete both (take *your* code out first!), open xaml again and f7 to see which file VS regenerated and then fill it back with your code.

Comment: Isn't that impossible? I expanded the XAML file, only 1 cs file appears as expected.

Comment: Did you include the auto-generated *.g file in your project?

Comment: Yes, I accidentally included auto-generated code, and the obj folder within the project.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally included auto-generated code, and the obj folder within the project.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error.  The culprit was due to "including" the temp/auto-generated folders.  Similar to what Sammarcow mentioned but here is a visual to help illustrate.

[image]